# Store and transfer values in a ascx control

Tags: asp.net, sql, ascx

I have a problem that I have been struggling with for some time, and it is regarding transfering values from one control to another.

Basically I have two .ascx controls. On control1: I have an email textbox called txtEmail. The txtEmail is used to save the email in the SQL table, and on update button click, I load Control2 that has a email textbox as well. I need the emailtext box from control1 to be available on email textbox on control2.

I have tried all kinds of different ways but to no avail. I even tried using delegates and events but I can't make it work.

Does anyone know how I can do this.

Regards

Please find below the code:

```
 public event EventHandler Notify;
     public string Email
    {
        get { return txtEmail.Text; }
        set {Email= value ; }
    }
```

//button that will handle the update

```
protected void btnUpdateDB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var email = txtEmail.Text.ToString();
        public BaseClass.BAL.MBAL m = new BaseClass.BAL.MBAL();
        var s = new BaseClass.Controllers.m();
        s.email=email;
        if(m.save(s)!=0) txtMsave.Text="Saved...."; 

}





//second control


 public  void notifyEmailChange(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        txtUsername.Text = member1.Email;
    }



protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       if(Page.IsPostBack)
       {
           member1.Notify += new EventHandler(notifyEmailChange);     

            }

    }

     public string email {
    set { txtUsers.Text = value; }}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't just need a validator to check the two email addresses are the same?

Comment: Ben, That is not necessary because the control1.email  is used to create a random password s if that is wrong, then they won't receive the password needed for login. It is a somehow different set up. Basically it is a software that is supposed to be used by known people(i.e. employee of company a or member of a given organisation like scouts etc....)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am trivializing the problem, but if you are wanting to be able to read/write to the text box on each of the custom controls, just make a public property that reads and writes to the textbox on each of the two controls.

```
    public string EmailAddress {
        get {
            return txtEmailAddress.Text;
        }
        set {
            txtEmailAddress.Text = value;
        }
    }
```

Now the page that contains the two controls can read the email address from the first control and write it into the email address text box in the second control.

If I am misunderstanding the problem, let me know.

Comment: Hi Zac, Your answer doesn't work simply because the control is loaded on postback and the string will be empty at that time.

Comment: asp.net provides multiple mechanisms to persist data, query string, view state, and session, all of which would work to persist the string through the postback.

Comment: Hi Zac, I tried those as well but for whatever reasons they were all empty say something like session["txtemail"]= txtemail.text; and then call it on the other control wasn't possible. I even used httpcontext but they were empty, I thought that it was just because I am using custom controls

Comment: if you cannot add an object to session and retrieve it after a postback, that is unrelated to your custom controls. Add the code you are trying to use in your question and we can try to help.

Comment: Hi, OK so this is the code: on the control1 protected bool updateuser(string Email){ user u= new user(); u.Email=txtemail.Text.Tostring();u.updateuser(u);}

Comment: first, if you are going to add code, it should go into the question so that it can be formatted and easily viewed. Second, this looks like a new question that is different from this question. please create a new question for your issue with saving the user's data and mark one of the answers to this question correct if they solve your issue.

Comment: Ok let me add the code then, I stopped because I couldn't see how to format it.

Comment: Code added, please have a look

Answer (score 1):

The way that I have done this in the past is to have

1. UserControl1 have a custom event called (for instance) Notify.
2. The containing control wires Notify to an EventHandler
3. When notify fires (on the update) the consuming event handler fires and this event handler updates the email on UserControl2

Might seem overengineered but because UserControl2 can't "see" UserControl1 I think this is the way to go

**Example**

In UserControl1

```
public event EventHandler Notify;
```

and within the update button click event handler

```
if(Notify != null)
{
    Notify(this, new EventArgs());
}
```

In parent control

in Page_Load

```
ucUserControl2.Notify += new EventHandler(NotifyUserControl);
```

and to set the message

```
protected void NotifyUserControl(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    ucUserControl2.Email = ucUserControl1.Email;
}
```

You obviously need public properties in UserControls to expose the Email text